# Unable to render Jupyter notebook stored as lfs objects in Gitlab

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, git-lfs, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have just upgraded my Gitlab CE docker instance to 15.5.1 from 13.12(followed [upgrade path mentioned in Gitlab official docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#installation-using-docker) and done multiple upgrades) and now I'm not able to render jupyter notebooks stored as Git LFS objects in repo.

It displays below message when we try to render it
`This content could not be displayed because it is stored in LFS. You can download it instead.`
can we explicitly enable this feature by running a gitlab-rails command or so ? Or is this feature deprecated in latest Gitlab version ?
Thanks in advance.

I have tried looking in Gitlab admin section but there is no such option to enable this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's an open issue in Gitlab 15.5 version. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/385035